Regarding issue in GCP logs of Cronjob ap
In my private branch cron job app is executed for every 5 min correctly in GCP ,but in development branch its show just Application started only seems not executing for every 5 min while seeing in GCP logs
What will the main root cause for that issue?
I Tried but by checking all file i have created for deploying like dockerfile , dockerignore, deployment and k8s files needed for the cron job
Checked all pipelines once again
But If I redeployed the last version of my branch its working
I expect the main cause for the issue!

Are you asking how to debug a non-running cron job? If so, that sounds like a question for https://serverfault.com/
